# Use Tor proxy in ftplib to upload a file

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ftp, tor, proftpd

I want upload a file to a ftp server using Tor proxy to comunicate with a Hidden Service. I have seen several ways using `stem` and `socks` but I could not connect to an FTP yet.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import ftplib 
import os 

def upload(ftp, file):

    ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    if ext in(".txt", ".htm", ".html"):

        internet.ftp.storlines("STOR " + file ,open(file))
    else:
        internet.ftp.storbinary("STOR " + file, open(file, "rb"), 1024)

ftp = ftplib.FTP('jk5qbvzlgbmss3zh.onion')
ftp.login("proftpd","123123")

upload(ftp, "file.zip.gpg")
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?